# Cannot setup ssh keys on my github account

Tags: git, github, ssh

I generated ssh keys in ~/.ssh folder and added those keys to my github account but when I run the following command to test my ssh connection 
`$ ssh -T git@github.com`
I get the following error:
`ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out`
I am not able to understand the error here.

I added ssh key in my github account going into Settings >> SSH and GPG keys tab and then on new ssh key and copied the content from id_rsa.pub into the key.

Comment: What and how did you add to the github account? Be as specific as possible. Edit the question, don't reply in the comments. The fact that you speak of the thing you added in the plural is a very red flag already.

Comment: From where are you trying to access GitHub through SSH? If from work, there are chances that SSH to outside world is blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Try Source: https://help.github.com/articles/using-ssh-over-the-https-port

try this:

$ vim ~/.ssh/config

Add:
Host github.com

Hostname ssh.github.com

Port 443